# Include not working on server

Tags: php, string, replace

I am using

```
function load($c) {
    if (strpos($c, "Cyclos\\") >= 0) {
        include str_replace("\\", "/", $c) . ".php";
    }
}

spl_autoload_register("load");
```

It's correctly working on localhost. But after uploading it to the server, it's not working. How do I fix it?

Comment: waht for standing "java" in the subject?

Comment: because this script is related with a java app

Comment: how java app is engaged in this? if you think that it's plays a role (imho it's not), then past part of code that fetch data from php-app, but really java+str_replace in the subject have  no sence. btw, I've posted tha answer (updated a bit), does't it helped?

Comment: I updated the title, as this problem is related to the `include` statement. It may require a different path on the server, as the physical directory will be different from the URL path.

Answer (score 0):

You have two errors here:

1. `strpos()` is a case-sensitive function, you should use `stripos()` instead. The same goes for `str_replace()`, you should use `str_ireplace()`. But since you are only replacing a backslash in your code, is doesn't make a difference in this case.
2. `strpos()` and `stripos()` return `false` if no occurrences are found, and `(int) false == 0`, so if on occurency if will pass it.

Try this one:

```
function load($c) {
    if (stripos($c, "Cyclos\\") !== false) {
        include str_replace("\\", "/", $c) . ".php";
    }
}

spl_autoload_register("load");
```

However, the reason may be different on different filesystems, on localhost you maybe have a case-insensitive filesystem (NTFS for example), and "cyclos.php" is the same as "Cyclos.php", while on **nix systems with EXT* filesystems case variations in file name will play a role.